# "Inject" Objective-C data into a UIWebView that loads a local HTML file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to load a UIWebView with local HTML/CSS that is build to look like a nutrition label. The problem is, the data for the food lies inside of my iPhone app. Do I have to put all of my HTML into one enormous NSString object and concatenate my data into it, or is there a way to load the HTML from a local .html file, but somehow "inject" the data that is stored within Objective-C into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data to be injected is "safe", you could construct your "enormous NSString object" as a format string, sprinkled with `%@` markers, and use `stringWithFormat:` to perform the injection in a single move. This is how I construct the pages in the TidBITS News app, using pieces that all come from RSS. It's really quite painless.

Comment: Yeah, I was planning to use `stringWithFormat:`, I just wish I didn't have to. When I compress the HTML it isn't that big though, so I think that's what I'm going to go with.

Answer (score 1):

You can load basic html using NSData's method dataWithContentsOfFile and then use javascript to modify html  in the way you need.

Code would look something like this (using this [example](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview)):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"html"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (data) {  
    [webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"];  
}
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"
                     "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                     "script.text = \"function myFunction() { "
                        "var field = document.getElementById('field_3');"
                        "field.value='Calling function - OK';"
                     "}\";"
                     "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a hybrid of both- have an HTML file in the app that you load, then replace certain strings in that before giving it to the UIWebView. So for example, you could have a file like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title><!--foodName--></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><!--foodName--></h1>
<p>Calories / 100g: <!--foodCalories--></p>
</body>
</html>
```

You'd load that into Cocoa, then replace your special placeholder comments with the actual values you want.

```
NSDictionary *substitutions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                               @"Carrots", @"foodName",
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], @"foodCalories",
                               // add more as needed
                               nil];

NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foodCard" ofType:@"html"] 
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                            error:nil];

for(NSString *substitutionKey in substitutions)
{
    NSString *substitution = [[substitution objectForKey:substitutionKey] description];
    NSString *searchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!--%@-->", substitutionKey];

    [html replaceOccurrencesOfString:searchTerm withString:substitution options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [html length])];
}

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 2 you can use `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script` within a UIWebView subclass to execute JS scripts in your webview. This is the best way to inject data from the "Objective-C part" of your application.

Cf: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: